# Monitor remote FTP directory

Tags: python, ftp

I only have FTP access to a directory on a remote server and would like to get the contents of new files as soon as they appear in the directory.

Is there any thing like FAM for Python that lets me monitor for new files over FTP?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If polling the server is an option:

```
from ftplib import FTP
from time import sleep

ftp = FTP('localhost')
ftp.login()

def changemon(dir='./'):
    ls_prev = set()

    while True:
        ls = set(ftp.nlst(dir))

        add, rem = ls-ls_prev, ls_prev-ls
        if add or rem: yield add, rem

        ls_prev = ls
        sleep(5)

for add, rem in changemon():
    print('\n'.join('+ %s' % i for i in add))
    print('\n'.join('- %s' % i for i in remove))

ftp.quit()
```