# How to watch and and monitor ftp mounted point for new created files using Python

Tags: python, ftp, filesystems, mount, inotify

I am able to watch local directories using `inotify` kernel subsystem based solutions. There are some python projects too which are working on top of inotify like [pyinotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify), [PyInotify](https://github.com/dsoprea/PyInotify), [fsmonitor](https://github.com/shaurz/fsmonitor) and [watchdog](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog).

I have mounted remote ftp server in local directory using [curlftpfs](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/) so all syncing is easy now. But inotify is not able to watch network mounted points like local directories.

I want to track if there is new files added to ftp server. How can I achieve like I do for local directory using inotify based solution.

Comment: Assuming you can identify when new files show up, how do you plan on identifying when a file has been successfully and *completely* transferred?

Comment: I dont know exactly how does NFS/curlftpfs shows the files in local filesystem

Answer (score 1):

It can hardly work. The FTP protocol has no API to notify a client about the changes. The curlftpfs would have to continually poll the remote folder to provide the notification for inotify or other similar tool. It hardly does that.

You have to poll the FTP folder yourself.

See for example [Monitor remote FTP directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12118011/850848).

Comment: I wanted to avoid polling server :(

Comment: You cannot avoid that. The FTP protocol has no API to notify a client about the changes.

Comment: Thanks Martin Prikryl